# How to convert SqlDbType datetime to string in VB

Tags: vb.net, datetime, sqldbtype

I want to display the date column into a textbox that a stored procedure returns. The error displays the column name. 
Thank you for your help!

SQL stored procedure:

```
SELECT MAX(NrTimesUpdated) AS NrTimesUpdated,   
       CONVERT(varchar(20),MAX(DateModified),101) AS DateEntered
FROM   Credentials
WHERE ID = @ID
END
```

VB code:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
cmd = New SqlCommand("get_credentials", cn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lblID.Text
Dim rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
If rdr.Read Then
   lblDate.Text = rdr("DateEntered").ToString().Trim()
End If
rdr.Close()
```

Comment: It returns nothing I get the error label to show "DateEntered".

Comment: is the "error label" something different than `lblDate`? And is there a column named "DateEntered" in the db?  Pretend we dont know a thing about your app.

Comment: The Stored Procedure command is on Page Load. When you click on view page will load all the data is required. This command I need to populate a textbox field with a date and it reads the stored procedure command (I debug it), it reads the reader and when it readslblDate.Text = rdr("DateEntered").ToString().Trim() it jumps out and goes directly to my catch error lable and returns DateEntered.

Comment: lblDate.Text is where I want the data to display

Comment: _it jumps directly to my catch error_ so? where is that code? This seems to be an exception triggered by something like a null in your field while you try to read it. But what is the error message?

Comment: The code is posted. I simply added a try block so I can step to it and see where is the error coming from. When I get on the   lblDate.Text = rdr("DateEntered").ToString().Trim() with the F10 key it jumps to: Catch ex As Exception
                    lblMsg.Text = ex.Message and displays on the screen DateEntered. That is all it displays. I am not much familiar with VB but I do know that C# has conversions from datetime to string and that is what I am trying to find the code that converts datetime to string. Thank you!